# Encrypted value length using Google KMS API in C# is different from the length of encrypted text generated directly from the API in postman

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I am trying to encrypt the text in C# using google KeyManagementService.
I am not able to decrypt the cipher generated by `KeyManagementServiceClient.Encrypt` using `KeyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt` method. Decryption gives me:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="Decryption failed: the ciphertext is invalid.")
```

I tried to use the google Try this API link to get the cipher and the length of the cipher generated by google API and the C# result are different.

Ex: 
           plaint text: `text`

cipher from C#:

```
TaRQSJ2KXrdmJJT6MmlD8RrcxzPJEa1jwAXWJ1puXg6nbl80aBcSLQBqSYOONfXhpZx8SyxCdB6mqTgr8uLJoAjva+Q4kN/p0+9RL2Sp2mHq4wjmZQ==
```

cipher from API:

```
TaRQSJ2KXv9ntnS7IszL077KNPtGJnqF9pSNiWANsq8gD0whezUSKwBqSYOOKKMifiWrfPDnHL5xETHPPlms0ztjkqa5hjdtkHwpzByLzi68A40
```

Has anyone phased the issue?

Here is my sample code

```cs
 KeyManagementServiceClient keyManagementServiceClient =KeyManagementServiceClient.Create(channel);
  byte[] plaintext=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
  EncryptRequest request = new EncryptRequest
   {
       CryptoKeyPathName = new CryptoKeyPathName("test-project", "global", "test-key", "encryption-key"),
        Plaintext = ByteString.CopyFrom(plaintext),
   };
   EncryptResponse response =keyManagementServiceClient.Encrypt(request);
   var cipher = 
   Convert.ToBase64String(response.Ciphertext.ToByteArray());

 //Decrypt
  ByteString ciphertext = ByteString.CopyFrom(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cipher));

  DecryptRequest req = new DecryptRequest
        {
            CryptoKeyName = new CryptoKeyName("test-project", "global", "test-key", "encryption-key"),
            Ciphertext = ciphertext,
        };
        // Make the request
        DecryptResponse res = keyManagementServiceClient.Decrypt(req);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've base64-encoded the results of encrypting, but you haven't base64-decoded it before you try to decrypt it.

In the line

```
ByteString ciphertext = ByteString.CopyFrom(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cipher));
```

It should instead look something like

```
ByteString ciphertext = ByteString.FromBase64(cipher);
```

(Note also that the [ByteString class](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/byte-string) has built-in methods for going to/from Base64, if that's what you're looking to do.)

Comment: Thank you that worked for decryption (not throwing the exception). But the decrypted value is not same as the initial input. The decrypted value is something like this `dGVzdA==` instead of `test`

Comment: Well, it was my mistake. Got what I am expecting by just changing how I am converting my data to ByteString. Thank you so much @bdhess